# Error accessing the registry in web browser desktop application

Tags: c#

I am working on web browser application. Many of the website is working properly but some of the website it showing update the browser like flipkart.com website. And so for I am creating the registry key for working website in the latest ie explorer but in that error shows that "Errors accessing the registry". Please help me to solve this error. Here is my code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Helper.SetBrowserEmulation(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, IE.IE10);
}

internal class Helper
{
   public static void SetBrowserEmulation(
   string programName, IE browserVersion)
   {
      programName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
      RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
      "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main" +
      "\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
      if (regKey != null)
      {
        try
        {
          regKey.SetValue(programName, browserVersion,
          RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          throw new Exception("Error writing to the registry", ex);
        }
     }
     else
     {
       try
       {
         regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software" +
         "\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main" +
         "\\FeatureControl", true);
         regKey.CreateSubKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
         regKey.SetValue(programName, browserVersion,
         RegistryValueKind.DWord);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         throw new Exception("Error accessing the registry", ex);
       }
     }
   }
 }

internal enum IE
{
  IE7 = 7000,
  IE8 = 8000,
  IE8StandardsMode = 8888,
  IE9 = 9000,
  IE9StandardsMode = 9999,
  IE10 = 10000,
  IE10StandardsMode = 10001
}

private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string WebPage = UrlTextBox.Text.Trim();
  webBrowser1.Navigate(WebPage);
}
```